# How can add small object in GPUImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, gpuimage

I am using GPUImage framework for a application which creates gifs.

The application add  filters, cadres, sticker and text on movie.

My problem is about stickers and text. How can add them and make it able to drag? (I know how to change frame with drag)

[image]
[image]

These are two image to understand what i want to do.

Below is code used for created movie, filter and cadres:

```
self.imageMovie = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithPlayerItem:self.avPlayerItem];
    self.imageMovie.playAtActualSpeed = YES;
    self.imageMovie.delegate = self;

    self.imagePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cadru_wanted.png"] smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
    [self.imagePicture forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
    [self.imagePicture processImage];


    self.selectedFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
    [self.imageMovie addTarget:self.selectedFilter];


    self.blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
    [self.imagePicture addTarget:self.blendFilter atTextureLocation:1];
    [self.selectedFilter addTarget:self.blendFilter atTextureLocation:0];
    self.blendFilter.mix=1;

    [self.blendFilter addTarget:self.gpuImageViewObj ];
    [self.imageMovie startProcessing];
```